# How to Improve this trigger

Tags: trigger

Relationship:  `Invoice__c` is parent and `InvoiceLineItem__c` is child. `InvoiceMaster__c` is parent and `InvoiceLineItem__c` is child

scenario: `Invoice__c` contains 2 picklist values, `After` and `Before`. Same picklist values are available in  `InvoiceMaster__c` as well along with checkbox. Whenever I create an `Invoice__c`, automatically `InvoiceMaster__c` record has add to `InvoiceLineItem__c` based on picklist values.

for more information please check trigger logic

Trigger:

```
trigger InvoiceLineInsertion on Invoice__c (After insert,after Update) {
    if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isAfter){
        Invoiceclass.invoiceDetail(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class Invoiceclass {
    public static void invoiceDetail(list<Invoice__c> invoiceLst){
        system.debug('trigger is calling@@@');
        List<InvoiceLineItem__c> invLst=new List<InvoiceLineItem__c>();
        List <InvoiceMaster__c>afterlst=new List<InvoiceMaster__c>();
        List <InvoiceMaster__c>beforelst=new List<InvoiceMaster__c>();

        //based on picklist value quering existing database
        afterlst=[Select id,Active__c,Name,Type__c,Amount__c from InvoiceMaster__c where Active__c=true AND Type__c='After'];

        //based on picklist value quering existing database
        beforelst=[Select id,Active__c,Name,Type__c,Amount__c from InvoiceMaster__c where Active__c=true AND Type__c='Before'];

        //trigger Logic
        for(Invoice__c c:invoiceLst){
            if(c.Type__c=='After'){
                for(InvoiceMaster__c s:afterlst)  {
                    InvoiceLineItem__c ac=new InvoiceLineItem__c();
                    ac.Invoice__c=c.id;
                    ac.InvoiceMaster__c=s.id;
                    ac.Amount__c=s.Amount__c;
                    ac.Name=s.Name;
                    invLst.add(ac);
                }
            }
            if(c.Type__c=='Before'){
                for(InvoiceMaster__c s: beforelst)  {
                    InvoiceLineItem__c ac=new   InvoiceLineItem__c();
                    ac.Invoice__c=c.id;
                    ac.InvoiceMaster__c=s.id;
                    ac.Amount__c=s.Amount__c;
                    ac.Name=s.Name;
                    invLst.add(ac);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!invLst.isEmpty()){
            insert invLst;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: So.... you want people here to write your trigger properly for you? Or do you have a specific question other than "Make it Better for me"?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're asking for help in improving this trigger helper, but which part do you think needs improvement?  Why do you think this needs to be improved?

Comment: like avoiding for within for loop  or any good practise for perticular this trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this trigger (and trigger helper) doesn't really need any improvement.

Your helper is bulkified (no soql or DML inside of loops), and the class is short.

The nested for loops here appear to be unavoidable. You have multiple `InoviceMaster__c` records that are being used as templates to generate `InvoiceLineItem__c` records for each newly inserted/updated `Invoice__c`, and setting `ac.Invoice__c = c.Id;` requires the nested loop.

About the only suggestions I could make are:

- Really think about whether or not you need this code to be run `after update`. As is, any update to an `Invoice__c` record will cause additional `InvoiceLineItem__c` records to be created. I have doubts that this is desirable behavior.
- You can save a minuscule amount of time by setting name-value pairs in the SObject constructor instead of using dot-notation to set fields, and adding the new record directly to your `List`.

What I mean by my second point is instead of doing this:

```
InvoiceLineItem__c ac = new InvoiceLineItem__c();
ac.Invoice__c=c.id;
ac.InvoiceMaster__c=s.id;
ac.Amount__c=s.Amount__c;
ac.Name=s.Name;
invLst.add(ac);
```

You could do this:

```
invList.add(newInvoiceLineItem__c(
    Invoice__c = c.id,
    InvoiceMaster__c = s.id,
    Amount__c = s.Amount__c,
    Name = s.Name
);
```

Beyond that, about the only 'improvement' that could be made would be breaking things up a bit more to achieve better separation of concerns (a la [Apex Enterprise Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns)), but I'd argue that would be overkill based on the simplicity of the provided code (in other words, just keeping logic, outside of triggers, in classes is probably good enough for you at this time).

If anything, I'd point you to start looking at using a trigger framework such as the [tidy trigger pattern](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers) or [Hari Krishnan's trigger framework](https://krishhari.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/an-architecture-framework-to-handle-triggers-in-the-force-com-platform/).

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?